# My sound will not work on explorer or firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I load the .ogg and .mp3 files through jQuery.  Loaded it up on my website for a testrun and it only works in chrome.  What is wrong?  Here is a link to the site if needed:
http://willowshelley.com/japanese

Here a chunk from my jQuery.  All of the audio functions look like this one:

```
$("#cat").click(function(){
$("<audio></audio>").attr({ 
    'src':'audio/cat.mp3', 
    'volume':1,
    'autoplay':'autoplay'
}).appendTo("body");
$("<audio></audio>").attr({ 
    'src':'audio/cat.ogg', 
    'volume':1,
    'autoplay':'autoplay'
}).appendTo("body");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Look this:

[Supported_media_formats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats)

check the version of the browser you're looking at.

At the moment the audio tag is not very supported.

Comment: Is there a more supported way to go about this than the audio tag?

Comment: You may rely on some plugin already, like:[jplayer](http://www.jplayer.org/), [html5media](http://html5media.info/) or you could try this [mozilla-develop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Configuring_servers_for_Ogg_media), but I have not tested and are not sure functions for explorer!